# icefaces htmlselectbooleancheckbox uncheck not working

Tags: checkbox, server-side, icefaces-1.8

I am using icefaces 1.8.2 and i have a HtmlBooleanCheckbox on my page that I need to uncheck when certain circumstances are met.

the checkbox on the page is like this

```
<ice:selectBooleanCheckbox id="accepttermscheckbox"
    binding="#{managedBean.termsAgreement}"
    validator="#{managedBean.validateAgreement}">
</ice:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

and the binded object is a property of the managed bean with proper getter and setter

```
private HtmlSelectBooleanCheckbox termsAgreement;
```

i can check the checkbox in code, validator works fine and all the stuff i do with it are ok too but I just cant find a way to uncheck it on the server side.

I tried:

```
termsAgreement.setValue(Boolean.FALSE)
termsAgreement.setValue(null)
termsAgreement.setSelected(false)
```

but nothing works. Even if I debug it it shows value = null but when the page renders it still appears checked.
Once I check it I just cant get it unchecked unless I click it manually on the page.

funny thing is that

```
termsAgreement.setValue(Boolean.TRUE)
```

works fine.

Anyone any tips how I can uncheck it server side on the binded object?
Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are facing a common issue faced by ICEfaces/JSF developers.

First of all, you need to understand how JSF lifecycle works.

Following is a good article to read.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jsf2/

For your case, bind a value to `<ice:selectBooleanCheckbox>`.

For example `value="#{managedBean.termsAgreed}"`.

```
<ice:selectBooleanCheckbox id="accepttermscheckbox"
    binding="#{managedBean.termsAgreement}"
    validator="#{managedBean.validateAgreement}"
    value="#{managedBean.termsAgreed}">
</ice:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

Do not try to change the value from the component. Always change value from the value binding. In this example, you must change the value `termsAgreed`.

If your action/actionListener is not immediate, i.e `immediate="false", which is the default value, then changing the value in server-side will check/uncheck checkbox component.

If you are using `immediate="true"`, then you must call `resetValue()` method in your component, `HtmlSelectBooleanCheckbox`:

```
termsAgreement.resetValue();
```

Ideally, you shouldn't call `setValue()` methods in components. You will understand it when you understand the JSF lifecycle.

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I didn't know you had to explicitly write the value attribute when you already had binding. I thought binding does all that stuff for you. Anyway when I did setSubmitedValue(false) it also worked though I am not convinced thats how I should do it. Your solution seems to be more of a best practice while mine looks more like a hack.

Comment: You are welcome! Don't use setSubmittedValue() method also. As you said, many people use it as a hack. But those methods (setValue(), setSubmittedValue()) are part of JSF lifecycle. That's why I said you will understand it more clearly when you read about JSF lifecycle.